# Yii2 : Image not export to excel sheet in Kartik GridView

Tags: yii2, export-to-excel, yii2-grid, yii2-dynagrid

I have used the [Yii2-grid](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-grid) and [Yii2-dynagrid](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-dynagrid). when I go to export image column from grid view but image column not exported and it shows blank cell in excel sheet.

Here my code.

`$model->p_image` is live server image url like `https://www.exaple.com/uploads/image.png`

```
<?php
     // Gridview Setting array 
  $setting = [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'showPageSummary' => false,
        'floatHeader' => true,
        'autoXlFormat' => true,
        'pjax' => true,
        'hover'=>true,
        'pjaxSettings' => ['options' => ['id' => 'kv-pjax-container']],
        'panel' => [
            'heading' => false,
            'footer' => false,
            'beforeOptions' => ['style' => 'padding:10px 0px'],
        ],
        'panelBeforeTemplate' => '
            <div class="pull-left" style="padding-top: 10px">                             
                {summary}    
             </div>
             <div class="pull-right">
                 <div class="btn-toolbar kv-grid-toolbar" role="toolbar">
                     {toolbar}
                 </div>    
             </div>
             {before}
             <div class="clearfix"></div>',
        'panelTemplate' => '{panelBefore}{items}{pager}',
        'export'=>[
            'label' => 'Export Data',
            'fontAwesome' => true,
            'showConfirmAlert' => false,
            'target' => \kartik\grid\GridView::TARGET_BLANK
        ],
        'toolbar' =>  [
            ['content'=>'{dynagrid}'],
            '{export}',
            '{toggleData}',
        ],
        'exportConfig' => [
            \kartik\grid\GridView::CSV => ['filename' => $fileTitle.time()],
            \kartik\grid\GridView::PDF => [
                'filename' => $fileTitle.time(),
                'config' => [
                    'methods' => [
                        'SetHeader' => [str_replace("_", ' ', $fileTitle)],
                        'SetFooter' => ['{PAGENO}'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            \kartik\grid\GridView::EXCEL => [
                'filename' => $fileTitle.time(),
            ],
        ]
    ] ?>

<?php
                    $dynagrid = DynaGrid::begin([
                        'columns' => [
                            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

                            [
                                'attribute' => 'p_image',
                                'value' => function($model) {
                                    return $model->p_image;
                                },
                                'format' => ['image',['width'=>'45','class'=>'img-circle']],
                                'filter' => false,
                            ],
                            'p_asin',
                            'p_title',
                        ],
                        'theme' => 'panel-info',
                        'showPersonalize'=>true,
                        'allowThemeSetting' => false,
                        'allowFilterSetting' => false,
                        'allowSortSetting' => false,
                        'submitButtonOptions' => ['class' => 'btn btn-success'],
                        'gridOptions' => $setting,  <------ grid setting array
                        'options' => ['id' => 'dynagrid-product-data'] // a unique identifier is important
                    ]);
                    DynaGrid::end();
                ?>
```

Comment: I use `'format' => 'html'` generating manually the `img` for the `value` field, and it is properly exported

Comment: I have already used `'format' => 'html'`. But no luck. @gmc

Comment: Using as value `function($model){ return "<img src='".$model->p_image."'"; }` ?

Comment: I have try this but again no luck. @gmc